# How to show 10 product in django template by using _set(reverse lookup class)?

Tags: django, django-template-filters

```
{% for i in meal_category %}
    {% for item in i.product_set.all %}                
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 isotope-item {{ i|lower }} mb-5">
                    <div class="menu-list">
                        <span class="menu-list-product">
                            <img width="80" height="80" src="{{ item.image.url }}" alt="">
                        </span>
                        <h5>{{ item.name }} <span>৳ {% if item.discount %} {{ item.price|sub:item.discount }} {% else %}  {{ item.price }} {%endif%}</span></h5>
                        <p>{{ item.description|truncatewords:6 }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
      {% endfor %}  
{% endfor %}
```

Above code working nested loop(category wise product). The first loop work for the category and the second for category wise product. How to show 10 products belong a specific category?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this taking last user product IDs in views.

```
last_ten_product = product.objects.filter(since=since).order_by('-product_id')[:10]
```

Comment: I want to do this on template, not views.py

Answer (score 0):

just create a method in your model  and call it in template

```
self.product_set.all()[0:10]
```

Comment: In the above code working nested loop. First work for category and nested work for category wise product.
This will not work on the template. It will work on views.py.

Comment: if you want show products relational to pecific category? do this  yourproductmodel.objects.filter(category__name=yourname)[0:10]